Trying to see if $\lfloor x - y\rfloor = \lfloor x\rfloor - \lfloor y\rfloor$
So let $\lfloor x\rfloor = n,\ \lfloor y\rfloor = m$
Then by definition we know that: $ n \leq x < n + 1$ and $ m \leq y < m + 1$
But when I subtract the 2 inequalities together, I get $n - m \leq x - y < n- m$
How can $n - m \leq x - y$ and $x - y < n- m$ since 1 is saying (greater than or equal) and other is saying (strictly less than). Am I missing something here?

If $a < b$ and $c<d$ then $-d < -c$ so $a-d < b-c$, not $a-c < b-d$.

Try $x=1, y=0.5$

Subtracting the inequality for $y$ means reversing inequality signs:
$$(n\le x) \land( y<m+1) \implies n-m-1< x-y$$

@BobMarley You can not subtract inequalities like that.

@geetha290krm What's a good strategy to come up with such counterexamples

We have $3<4$ and $2<5$, but when we subtract the two inequalities we get $1<-1$.
Basically, you can't subtract inequalities the way you did. You can add inequalities. But to subtract two inequalities is to first multiply all sides of the second one by $-1$, then add them. And what happens when you multiply all sides of an inequality with $-1$? The inequality signs flip. This needs to be taken into account before adding them together.
So really, the correct way to subtract your two inequalities is to first transform the second one into $-m-1<-y\leq -m$ and then add that to $n\leq x<n+1$ to get
$$
n-m-1<x-y<n-m+1
$$
